# RFC5321 "receiver should check [...] reply code" (why?)

Tags: smtp, rfc

In SMTP `commands` are sent by the `sender` and `responses` which all begin with a numeric `code` are sent by the `receiver`.

but then there's this bit:

[RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.1) sec4.2

```
Whenever possible, a receiver-
SMTP SHOULD test the first digit (severity indication) of the reply
code.
```

Huh? Is that an error in the RFC? Do they mean `sender` instead of `receiver`?

next paragraph they say `sender`.

```
Consequently, a sender-SMTP MUST be prepared to handle codes not
specified in this document and MUST do so by interpreting the first
digit only.
```

That bit makes sense,

Comment: I don't see it in the errata. Report it and you could become famous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me. [Submit errata](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata.php).